# CloudFront - NodeJS Signed Cookie Setup

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have been reading through the various CloudFront documentation on how to set up signed cookies as the method of allowing access to my s3 bucket. I have completed the following steps:

1. Create a distribution using a custom SSL certificate with a CNAME of files.mysite.com
2. Adjust Behavior to Restrict Viewer Access = Yes and Trusted Signers = Self
3. Created a CloudFront Key Pair

I am now at the stage of implementing code to be able to sign the code on my backend to access the data, but I'm not exactly sure how to approach setting it up with my current use of s3 signing.

Right now I have a route set up to sign my s3 data to be able to upload and get my bucket files, while also saving a link to that s3 file path in my db to be used as links on my site to the file:

```
appRoutes.get('/sign', function(req, res){
    aws.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY, region: process.env.AWS_REGION});

    var uploadDate = new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var fileNameFormatted = req.query.file_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

    var s3 = new aws.S3()
    var options = {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
      Key: req.user.organizationId + '/' + uploadDate + '/' + fileNameFormatted,
      Expires: 60,
      ContentType: req.query.file_type,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', options, function(err, data){
      if(err) return res.send('Error with S3')

        console.log('This is the data: ' + data);
      res.json({
        signed_request: data,
        url: 'https://' + process.env.AWS_BUCKET + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + req.user.organizationId + '/' + uploadDate + '/' + fileNameFormatted
      });
    });
});
```

With javascript on the client-side in my view that triggers this route when a file is uploaded:

```
function upload(file, signed_request, url, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", signed_request);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            done();
        };
    };
    xhr.send(file);
};

function sign_request(file, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(file);
    xhr.open("GET", "/app/sign?file_name=" + file.name + "&file_type=" + file.type);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(response);
            done(response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

document.getElementById("file-input").onchange = function() {
    var file = document.getElementById("file-input").files[0];
    if (!file) return
        sign_request(file, function(response) {
            console.log('sign_request client file: ' + file);
            console.log('sign_request client response: ' + response);
            upload(file, response.signed_request, response.url, function() {
                document.getElementById("preview").src = response.url;
                document.getElementById("file-output").value = response.url;
            });
        });
};
```

With this setup I'm not sure how CloudFront signed cookies fit in either my client or server-side code. I know the purpose is to be the point of access to these files with `files.mysite.com/s3-file-path`, rather than `s3bucket.aws.com`, but would I configure additional client side code to trigger another sign route with my cloudfront signed cookie and then save that link?

Comment: The point of CloudFront signed cookies is that you don't need to sign the URLs in order to enable an authorized user to be able to download the files.  CloudFront will authenticate the request based on the cookie rather than the URL.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you for the comment. So are you saying that I should change the stored s3 link in my db to my cloudfront access point and then sign the cookie on user authentication, rather than during the process of uploading the file? I guess to your point, at what point should the cookie be set to allow authorized users to access files associated with their credentials?

Comment: Signed cookies seem to be most appropriately used for authorizing downloads... I would be hesitant to endorse the idea of using signed cookies to authorize uploads.  I *think* it is possible, but it doesn't intuitively feel like a good idea, and there may be other complications, depending on which S3 region is involved.  I notice you are uploading files with the `public-read` ACL, which typically makes the files downloadable by anyone, so... perhaps you should clarify what you're *really* trying to accomplish, rather than focusing for the moment on how you're trying to accomplish it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sorry for a bit of confusion on my end with my comment. I don't plan to use cloudfront with the uploading of the files. I just plan on using it with a url when users are then trying to access (GET request) the files located in s3. As a result, should I be signing the cookies in a completely separate process from my initial question? Maybe attach the signed cookie to the user when they are authorized?